# Midpoint method, error and tolerance

Tags: numerical-methods

I am asked to find the root of a function, using the midpoint technique. Now I have some definition questions. In one question I am asked to find the root with error $\delta \le 10^{-3}$. In another question I am asked to find a root wit **tolerance** $\tau≤ 10^{-3}$

What exactly is meant by tolerance?

Comment: Is this the **bisection method**? The next bracketing method (constructing midpoints and choosing new sub-intervals) would be rergula falsi and its variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tolerance is the largest acceptable relative error. The tolerance is the parameter fed to the solver, the error is the difference between the exact solution and the computed approximation.